# Show existence of periodic solution to $x'=f(t,x)$ where $f(t+T,x)=f(t,x)\ \forall t$, $\exists p,q|\forall t,f(t,p)>0>f(t,q)$ and $f\in C^{\infty}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x'(t) = f(t,x)$ where $f\in C^{\infty}$ and $f(t+T,x)=f(t,x)$ for all $t$. Furthermore, there exist $p,q$ such that for all $t$ we have $f(t,p)>0$ and $f(t,q) <0$. Show that there is a periodic solution $x(t)$ to this equation with $p<x(0)<q$. (I left this last requirement out of the title due to space restrictions)

I didn't really get far on this question. I need to show that there is an $x(t)$ such that $x' = f(t,x)$ and $x(t+T)=x(t)$ for all $t$. I know that $x(t+T) = x(t) + \int \limits_{t}^{t+T}f(t,x)dt$ so I should find a function $x(t)$ that satisfies the DE and has $\int _t^{t+T} fdt = \int_0^T f dt =0$. By the periodicity of $f$ I will restrict my attention to $0\leq t <T$.

Now, I know there exists an $p<m(t)<q$ such that $f(t,m(t)) = 0$ for all $t$ by the following: if we fix $t$, the fact that $f(t,p)>0$ and $f(t,q)<0$ and the fact that $f$ is continuous guarantees a number $m$ exists such that $f(t,m) = 0$, however, for different $t$ this $m$ need not be the same, depending on the shape of $f$ in the strip $(t,x) \in [0,T)\times [p,q]$. However, this $m$ exists for every $t$ and by the fact that $f$ is continuous there exists a continuous function $m(t)$ such that $f(t,m(t))=0$ for all $t$. Now this $m(t)$ does guarantee that $\int _0^T f(t,m(t))dt = 0$ but there is no guarantee that $m'(t) = f(t,m(t))=0$, in which case $m(t)$ needs to be a constant. This is of course not necessary and so this $m(t)$ is only a solution if $m$ is a constant, but this is not clear from the question. So this is not a solution per se.

I intuitively think that there exists many functions $k(t)$ such that $\int_0^Tf(t,k(t))dt=0$. But I need to show the existence of such a function that also satisfies $k' = f(t,k(t))$.

I also was thinking the poincare map mapping a the solution at time $t$ to the solution at $t+T$ could be useful. If I could show it has a fixed point between $p$ and $q$ I would be done. However I am not sure how to continue this reasoning.

So yeah, I am not sure how to continue on this one. Any help would be appreciated, I think I might not be on the right track but I am not sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You write $\exists p,q f(t,p)>0>f(q,t)\forall t$. Is that $\exists p,q\forall t$ aor $\forall t\exists p,q$?

Comment: I see where I was unclear on this, thanks! I meant there exists $p$ and $q$ such that for all $t$ we have $f(t,p)>0>f(t,q)$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that for arbitrary $a\in[p,q]$, you obtain a solution $x_a\colon[0,T]\to [p,q]$ with $x_a(0)=a$ and $x_a'(t)=f(t,x_a)$. Consider the map $g\colon [p,q]\to\mathbb R$, $a\mapsto x_a(T)-a$ and show that $g$ is continuousa nd$g(p)>0>g(q)$. Conclude that $g(b)=0$ for some $b$ and that $x_b$ is the desired periodic solution.